# why jmap command running with exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException?

Tags: jvm, jmap

When I am running this command **jmap -heap 12671** on linux to see the current heap size of a java application running on my system then after displaying prem space information this exception is coming

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
       at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:197)
        at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:128)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.AssertionFailure: Invalid bucket id
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.Assert.that(Assert.java:32)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.BasicHashtable.bucket(BasicHashtable.java:62)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.SymbolTable.probe(SymbolTable.java:86)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.SymbolTable.probe(SymbolTable.java:74)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.InstanceKlass.findField(InstanceKlass.java:651)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapSummary$1StringStat.<init>(HeapSummary.java:279)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapSummary.printInternStringStatistics(HeapSummary.java:299)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapSummary.run(HeapSummary.java:150)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapSummary.main(HeapSummary.java:40)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: I also encountered a `InvocationTargetException` but the stack trace contained some other cause. The issue I had was that `jmap` was the one from the open jdk while the process was running in the sun vm.